# How to convert DbDataReader to NpgsqlDataReader?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, datatable, npgsql

How can I convert DbDataReader/DataTableReader object to NpgsqlDataReader object?

Actually I am writing some test cases. I need to mock a method and return NpgsqlDataReader object. I am able to create DataTableReader/DbDataReader object out of DataTable. But unable to convert it to NpgsqlDataReader.

Need help.

Comment: Actually I am trying to test some Database response. Part of my code returns an object containing a property, object of NpgsqlDataReader class. This property contains the response from the query. Currently, I am emulating the output as a DataTable object. But I need to pass this to my said property as a NpgsqlDataReader object to test the other functionalities.

Comment: You can't. If you have code that explicitly needs an NpgsqlDataReader then create one. You can't just take a different thing and apply magic to convert it. You may ask yourself if the code under test needs something as specific as an NpgsqlDataReader. Normally you would try to prevent that to make testing/exchanging things easier.

Comment: Valid argument @Ralf. But, we are able to create a DbDataReader object from DataTable. In that case, NpgsqlDataReader being a derived class of DbDataReader, there should be some mechanism that will help us to create NpsqlDataReader object from DataTable. Right?

Comment: No. NpsqlDataReader is a DbDataReader class that does use a Postgres Database as backend. You want one that uses a DataTable as Backend. The implementation is different. If you want to exchange behavior here you must work against a common interface. The most common thing is DbDataReader. You can exchange derived DbDataReader classes. But you can't for something already specialised like a NpgsqlDataReader. The best thing you can do is changing the code under test to use something less specialized.